# Android 4.4.4 - webview displaying a canvas

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

With the new version of Android (4.4.4), when I use LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, the webview begins to blink when the user click on a canvas.

If I remove LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, the problem no more exist but I need to enable it otherwise the rendering is too slow. I tried to set every background as transparent but it didn't work

Do you have this problem too ?

Comment: could you provide a link to the html with the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in general. Instead of setting LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE on the WebView (which creates a *separate* hardware accelerated layer) try making your [entire activity hardware accelerated](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling) and see if the problem goes away.